# If Snape knew that Pettigrew had a silver hand, why didn't Snape suggest that solution to Dumbledore's hand?

Tags: harry-potter

[image]

In the picture above, it shows a scene in *The Half-Blood Prince* where Snape tells "Wormtail" to run along before shoving Wormtail into his room with a wave of his wand. 
 Before Snape does, however, we are given a glimpse of Pettigrew's silver hand. If Snape knew this, why didn't he just suggest this solution to Dumbledore?

If he truly cared for Dumbledore, why didn't he just regrow the missing limb for Dumbledore instead of letting him die painfully, slowly, albeit surely?

Comment: I think Snape made it clear: “There is no halting such a spell forever.” Had something as mundane as amputation been sufficient, he would not have hesitated to do it. Consider cancer: while the tumor may be in a single limb, cancer cells may have metastasized throughout the body. Or imagine a mushroom: its visible portion is small, but its mycelium spread far underground. The point is that just because the effects of the curse were confined to a single hand, doesn’t mean it hadn’t insinuated itself into Dumbledore’s body in such a manner that it would be impossible to root out entirely.